# Install TP-Link TL-WN722N version 1.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I installed the latest Ubuntu version 18.04, I have a version 1.1 TP-Link TL-WN722N wifi adapter which worked on Windows. I plugged the usb to my Ubuntu and the network is found in the list of connections and I believe I installed the necessary driver, but the light on the adapter is still blinking and I'm not sure how to check if it's really working (seems like it's not..), the internet is super slow still..
What can I do? I contacted TP-Link and they told me there's no driver for Linux for this version. These are the logs, I have a Lenovo X220. 
ifconfig gives:

```
ifconfig
```

enp0s25: flags=4099  mtu 1500

```
    ether f0:de:f1:ee:7d:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)

    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000
```

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536

```
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

    RX packets 4321  bytes 371309 (371.3 KB)

    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    TX packets 4321  bytes 371309 (371.3 KB)

    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

wlp3s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500

```
    inet 192.168.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

    inet6 fe80::760:5bde:7711:af76  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>

    ether 74:e5:0b:f4:4e:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

    RX packets 186042  bytes 89778980 (89.7 MB)

    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    TX packets 42577  bytes 7297649 (7.2 MB)

    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

wlxc4e9841d8255: flags=4163  mtu 1500

```
    inet 192.168.1.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255

    inet6 fe80::54d5:6a2e:5104:8dc7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>

    ether c4:e9:84:1d:82:55  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

    RX packets 516  bytes 125709 (125.7 KB)

    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

    TX packets 116  bytes 19134 (19.1 KB)

    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

More logs can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwilcc6v0g5h5e9/network.txt?dl=0